# How to scan all contract created events?

Tags: contract-deployment

I'm attempting to index all contracts ever created on Ethereum mainnet.

Transactions without a `to` are transactions in which a contract is created. The new contract hash can be found in the `contractAdress`-property of the receipt.

This however does not include all contacts. Some contracts are created as the result of a call to function on another contract. Is there a generic way to find all the contracts generated in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I am not aware of any

> generic way

that exists for this, no.

You could build it, though.

Since you *can* track **all contracts represented by transactions without a** `to`, trawling the entire blockchain will return these on a first run. You could then query the blockchain for each contract returned, looking for all contracts deployed `from` these contracts, so on and so forth, until you return no deployed contracts from within a contract/function of another contract. Then, track `timestamp` of each tx block to see all the transactions in an 'indexed' order. I don't think it's a requisite that the contracts emit any events on creation, as @Rodrigo said, but am happy to be proved wrong.

If it were to work, it would take some time, and I'm not 100% sure these are exclusively the only ways contracts exist on chain.

Comment: Yeah that would indeed be possible, and kudos for the idea, but in practice that would be a nightmare to maintain 'progress'

Comment: Haha yes, yes it would ;) what are you trying to achevie overall? dm me!

Answer (score 0):

If this factory contract emit an event everytime a new contract is deployed through it then yes, you can track then.

Comment: Was asking in a more generic way. Is there a way to track all contract creations in some way or another?